# Sockets fails to emit inside of POST

Tags: node.js, reactjs, rest, sockets

Socket fails to emit inside of POST endpoint.

**socket.emit("message", messageArr);**

This POST does not emits any socket data. I tried to send some dummy data and its not working. 
**But when i use it outside of POST, the data comes in without problem.**

My idea is i need to **Emit message to FE every time when POST comes in.** Because its a Webhook for Twilio (sms).

```
 app.post("/twilio", (req, res) => {
        if (messageArr.number === req.body.To) {
          try {
            messageArr.body.push({ id: "client", text: req.body.Body });
          } finally {
            socket.emit("message", messageArr);
            console.log("Message Array", messageArr);
          }
        } else {
          messageArr = {
            number: req.body.To,
            body: [
              {
                id: "client",
                text: req.body.Body
              }
            ]
          };
          socket.emit("message", messageArr);
          console.log("Emit message array", messageArr);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

your calling socket inside a callback so it can't find the memory reference to it so declare a var above your app.post and call it so you can access it like shown below.

```
var _socket = socket;
app.post("/twilio", (req, res) => {
    if (messageArr.number === req.body.To) {
      try {
        messageArr.body.push({ id: "client", text: req.body.Body });
      } finally {
        _socket.emit("message", messageArr);
        console.log("Message Array", messageArr);
      }
    } else {
      messageArr = {
        number: req.body.To,
        body: [
          {
            id: "client",
            text: req.body.Body
          }
        ]
      };
      _socket.emit("message", messageArr);
      console.log("Emit message array", messageArr);
    }
```